# WiX "Undefined Preprocessor Variable" despite variable in .wxi file

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I have a WiX project in visual studio that contains two files: Product.wxs and config.wxi.

When I attempt to build this project, I get the following error: "Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.ProductName)'."

What am I doing wrong here that the Include file is apparently not being recognized?

### config.wxi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  <?Define Manufacturer = "My Company" ?>
  <?Define ProductName = "My Product" ?>
  <?Define Version = "1.0.0.0" ?>
  <?Define BuildType = "Development" ?>
  <?Define BuildTypeShort = "Dev" ?>
</Include>
```

### Product.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <?include config.wxi ?>
  <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="1033" Version="$(var.Version)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="6e7efd44-0149-416b-871d-418ba6365e1b">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MySetup" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductName)" />
        </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File Source="$(var.SomeProjectA.TargetPath)"/>
        <File Source="$(var.SomeProjectB.TargetPath)"/>
            </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "define" instead of "Define".

As here:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Include>
      <?define Manufacturer = "My Company" ?>
      <?define ProductName = "My Product" ?>
      <?define Version = "1.0.0.0" ?>
      <?define BuildType = "Development" ?>
      <?define BuildTypeShort = "Dev" ?>
    </Include>
```